# Considering an element only if its a child of another element

Tags: dart, polymer, dart-polymer

For example :`list-view` and `list-item`

I use them as:

```
<list-view>
   <list-item><list-item>
   <list-item><list-item>
   <list-item><list-item>
</list-view>
```

But how do i make `<list-item>` element valid if and only if its a child of `<list-view>`?

is there a formal way to do this in polymer?

to make it more clear sometimes i create polymer elements that are intended to be used inside and only inside another polymer element

Comment: What do you mean "make it valid"? Can you supply a little more information about what you want the element to do?

Comment: @DocDude I think he means something like the `<source>` tag can exist only as a child of specific tags like `<video>`

Comment: @JAre yes thats what i meant

Comment: @DocDude maybe display a warning on the console, i can do a manual check but i wonder if something like this is already built in

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So, the short answer here is no. I think as a general rule, the element shouldn't have to know anything about its parent elements. You can have a parent element that only displays `<list-item>` children, but does it add anything to have a `<list-item>` that won't appear outside of a `<list-view>`?

To take an example from vanilla HTML, an `<option>` only really makes sense inside a `<select>`, `<optgroup>` or `<datalist>` element, but you can put one in elsewhere and the browser doesn't complain. Likewise, if I include a `<source>` tag outside of a `<video>`, I don't see a console message (at least on Chrome and Firefox).

If you want to do something special in this case, you can check the parent node in the `attached` callback. Something like:

```
attached: function() {
  if (this.parentNode.localName !== 'list-view') {
    ...
  } else { 
    ...
  }
```

Of course, if you do this, and next week you come up with an awesome `<grid-list-view>` that could re-use your original `<list-item>`, you need to go back and change your list item. So I would use this pattern with caution and only if you see a tangible benefit to restricting where your component can be used.